# No folder on ubuntu - clamd.scan/clamd.sock

Tags: django, ubuntu

I am trying to install a [scanner](https://pypi.org/project/django-clamd/) for my Django application which refers to this place `/var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock` but I don't have the following folder on ubuntu 18+. I tried to install it using `sudo apt-get install clamav` but I still have no visible folery. How can I install it on ubuntu? or maybe he is in a different place.

Answer (score 1):

for the server files, you may need to install the daemon:

```
sudo apt-get install clamav clamav-daemon
sudo service clamav-freshclam restart
sudo service clamav-daemon restart
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is this file "clamd.sock" in the same place then? "CLAMD_SOCKET = '/var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock'"